# Where/How to instaniate an object to handle null reference exception

Tags: c#, constructor, nullreferenceexception, objectinstantiation

Hey guys kind of a simple question, I'm not exactly sure where/how to initialize a new object instance so I don't get this error.  I have a class object(Contact) that has another class object(ContactInfo) and sometimes the user decides not to input(instantiate) the ContactInfo object.  So later when I try to do a search via Contact.ContactInfo, I get the error.  Below I have the line of code where I get the error and then I have the two classes:

```
foreach (var Contact in Contacts)
{
    if (String.Equals(Contact._contactInfo.City.ToLower(), city, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
    {
        ContactsByCity.Add(Contact);
    }
}
```

and then the two classes:

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    private ContactInfo info;
    private ContactInfoLoader loader;
    public ContactInfo _contactInfo { get; set; }

    public Contact()
    { }
    public Contact(ContactInfo _info)
    {
        info = _info;           
    }
    public ContactInfo GetContactInfo()
    {
        loader = new ContactInfoLoader(this);
        return loader.GatherContactInfo();
    }     
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set;}

    public ContactInfo()
    { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee that the `ContactInfo info` won't be null after the `Contact` is constructed, you'll need to check for that at the time of construction. Consider something like this:

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    private ContactInfo info;
    public ContactInfo _contactInfo { get; set; }

    public Contact(ContactInfo _info)
    {
        if (_info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("_info");
        info = _info;
    }
    public Contact(ContactInfoLoader loader)
        : this(loader.GatherContactInfo())
    {
    }
}
```

#### Bonus:

A more standard style for the class definition but with equivalent semantics would be

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    //auto-generates a private field for you
    public ContactInfo Info { get; private set; }

    public Contact(ContactInfo info)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
        this.Info = info;
    }
    public Contact(ContactInfoLoader loader)
        : this(loader.GatherContactInfo())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the Bonus code but when I make the call to create a new Contact, I get errors such as:

Comment: 'AddressBook.Contact does not contain a definition for 'ContactInfo' from the following line:  String.Equals(Contact.ContactInfo.City.ToLower().  Also I get a 'AddressBook.Contact does not contain a definition for getContactInfo'

Comment: Another issue, when I create a new Contact, I never have a ContactInfo or ContactInfoLoader already instantiated to pass in to the Contact constructors.  I know I'm doing something really wrong here, I can't figure it out

Comment: @user2359626 You should take advantage of the vast amount of available resources on the web for teaching you C#. These new problems you're encountering are extremely basic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to avoid the exception, you can say:

```
if (Contact._contactInfo && 
    String.Equals(Contact._contactInfo.City.ToLower(), city,
                  StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
{
    ContactsByCity.Add(Contact);
}
```

alternatively, your parameterless constructor could add an empty `ContactInfo` object:

```
public Contact()
{
  _info = new ContactInfo();
  // and make sure the ContactInfo constructor creates non-null, City etc.
}
```

Comment: By adding an empty ContactInfo object, how would I make the ContactInfo constructor create non-null properties (city, state, etc)?

Comment: Within `public ContactInfo()`, set `City = ""; State = "";` and so on.

Comment: When I create a new Contact, I never have a ContactInfo or ContactInfoLoader already instantiated to pass in to the Contact constructors. I know I'm doing something really wrong here, I can't figure it out.  For example:

newContact.GetContactInfo();    // Here I want a Contact to add ContactInfo to it.

under my AddContact method:
            Contact newContact = new Contact();

and:
 if (String.Equals(Contact.ContactInfo.City.ToLower(), city, StringComparison.CurrentCulture))

I never make a call with Contact having ContactInfo or ContactInfoLoader being passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your parameterless constructor for `Contact`, I would instantiate a new `ContactInfo` object.

```
public Contact()
{ 
    info = new ContactInfo();
}
```

This will ensure that no matter which constructor gets called, any instantiated `Contact` object will have a non-null `ContactInfo` object associated with it.

If a null `ContactInfo` object is passed into your `Contact` constructor, you could do the following:

```
public Contact(ContactInfo _info)
{
   if(_info == null)
       _info = new ContactInfo();

   info = _info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the contract of the class is that `ContactInfo` can be `null` (because perhaps it is valid that a `Contact` not have `ContatctInfo`) then consumers will need to check for `null` before using the returned `ContactInfo`.

If, on the other hand, `Contact` is never valid without a `ContactInfo` then only provide constructors that take a `ContactInfo` and if that `ContactInfo` is null, it should throw an `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: Ok if I use the bonus code, how do I make the proper call to create new ContactInfo for a specific contact:                      newContact.GetContactInfo();
String.Equals(Contact.ContactInfo.City.ToLower()

Comment: BIG THANKS TO EVERYONE!!! I got it working and implemented much of what everyone said.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2359626 If you want to "thank" someone on here for a good answer, upvote their  question.  Then, pick the answer you think is the best answer (if there is one), and click the "check" to mark it as the answer.